# forEach loop inside RequestAnimationFrame

Tags: javascript, recursion, coffeescript, three.js

I would like to structure a (THREEjs) project I'm working on like this

```
    class Blah
       scene    : new THREE.Scene()
       renderer : new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
       camera   : new THREE.PerspectiveCamera()

       render : ( renderables )->

          renderables.forEach ( renderable )->
             renderable()

          @renderer.render( @scene, @camera ) 

   foo = new Blah()

   animateMovie =->
       requestAnimationFrame( animateMovie )     
       foo.render([baz.update, bar.update])
```

The `render` method takes an array of functions to update. Would having a loop inside `animateMovie`, which gets called recursively using `requestAnimationFrame`, cause stack overflow, and is there any performance issues with doing something like this.

Comment: You could take some strain off the call stack with `renderable() for renderable in renderables`.

Answer (score 0):

The `requestAnimationFrame()` method tells the browser to run a callback function right before the next repaint happens.

It’s particularly useful when using JavaScript for animations and repeating UI updates. Because it ties into the browser’s repaint timing, it produces a smoother effect than using something like `setInterval()`

The `requestAnimationFrame()` method only runs once. You can make it loop over-and-over again using a technique called recursion.